# delete a files with their name and path in another file .bat

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

I need to know if is possible to create a batch code, to read an file.txt and according the information there, access the folder path and delete file. 
In my file.txt, is a result of a sql query.

**my_file.txt**

```
file_name, file_path
abcd, D:/user/desktop/teste123
efgh, D:/user/desktop/folder789
```

The Batch needs to read "file_name" (to know the file to delete) and file_path (to know where to delete).

Is it possible? Help me pls

Thanks.

Comment: This is possible, yes: you read the content of that file, parse it as directory names and filenames, and do something with it.

Comment: Hi @Dominique, thanks for your reply, can you help me with this? Thanks

Comment: @Dominique downvoting my answer does not solve the fact that you posted incorrectly in the previous question, I suggest you learn a litle more about this site. Ignorance is going to bring you nowhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would run a for loop and split on the `,` delimeter and use each as a variable.

So as an untested example, here I will split the file entries and assign 2 tokens `%%i` and `%%j`

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=," %%i in (my_file.txt) do echo "%%i" "%%j"
```

Note that I added a double quotes to the tokens as it will possibly contain spaces.

Seeing that you want to do a delete, it will probably be something like:

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=," %%i in (my_file.txt) do echo del "%%j\%%i"
```

Where you would just remove the echo to perform the actual delete.

As per your comment, to skip the first line and exclude the `**rows affected` line you can use:

```
for /f "tokens=1,2 skip=1 delims=," %i in ('more my_file.txt ^| findstr /VI /C:"rows affected"') do del "%%j\%%i"
```

alternatively seeing that you are using more, you can exclude `skip=1` and simply use `+1` on the `more` command.

```
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=," %i in ('more +1 my_file.txt ^| findstr /VI /C:"rows affected"') do del "%%j\%%i"
```

Comment: Hi @gerhard I will try to do this and I'll come back to inform the result. Many thanks

Comment: All good, let me know about that trailing space after the comma as well so I can make changes if needed.

Comment: You can strip off leading spaces with another `for /f "tokens=*" %%x in ("%%j") do ...`

Comment: @LotPings. Yes thank you. I however doubt it does contain a space based on my numerous csv file exports from DB's :) but could build it in as a fail safe regardless.

Comment: @GerhardBarnard works very well :D many thanks. 
Only one more question, Can I skip the first line? I try to insert in the same FOR    for /f "skip=1" "tokens=1,2 delims=," %%i in (my_file.txt) do del "%%j\%%i"  and does not work, probably it is wrong. I need to create a new FOR to skip the first line? 
And them I can ignore the text (xx Rows affected) in my_file.txt?

I'm sorry for all the question, I'm new in batch. 
Thanks for all your help.

Comment: See the two new entries in the edit at the bottom of the answer.

Comment: Help me a lot. Thanks